# Get user location like Google now

Tags: ios, gps, core-location, cllocation, google-now

The Google app now has a feature called Google now. When Google now is active the app keeps locating the user even if the app is removed from background. 
How it does that? That isn't something forbidden by Apple?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both [Monitor Shape-Based Region](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH2-SW13) as well as [Significant-Change Location Service](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH2-SW8) continue to operate even when your app is not running.

It's only the [Standard Location Services](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH2-SW10) that require permission to run in the background.

Answer (score 1):

On iOS, you can not track someone's locations constantly while the app is in the background. However, you can create a geofence, which is like the functionality used in location-based reminders on the Reminders app. Try a [geofencing tutorial](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/geofencing-with-core-location/) for the code.